# how to display annotation in iphone app from created annotation in desktop or anywhere

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf

i am working on PDF annotation app i added PDF file  annotation in iPhone it working fine it annotation also  visible any reader but  created annotation from desktop  it visible in iPhone app ? how can do for this issue

Please Help Me

Comment: If you created a standard PDF annotation on iPhone and it is visible both in your application and on desktop, then standard PDF annotations created on desktop should also be visible in your iPhone app. If not, please post a link to the file with the annotation created on the iPhone and a link to the file with the annotation created on the desktop.

Comment: @iPDFdev how to get contents,title,image from pdf which is created from annotation from desktop

Comment: Please do not mix the topics. "How to get content, title, etc" is an entirely new question.

Comment: i am trouble please guide me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574559/how-to-get-image-from-fileattachment-annotation-in-pdf-file